# How to create a line with no gradient at the edges?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a line without any shadow and gradient.

I try to create a simple Container with color, as below:

https://dartpad.dev/?id=72468c06f2cab2d4025c0842828f3907

```
  return Container(
      height: 200,
      width: 100,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 3,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

But I got the result as this:

[image: line-1]

After zooming in, we see that it contains a gradient to the background color：

[image: line-2]

What should I do to create a completely pure line, without any shadows or gradients?

I've tried the clipBehavior property and all 4 values have the same result.

Comment: in general you cannot do that, you could do that in certain cases but in general there is no way to avoid that

Comment: @pskink Thanks for your reply! Why can't I do this? Is there any documentation to describe this behavior? What is the name of this behavior?

Comment: because you dont know where your container is located: what if you change `height: 200,` to `height: 201,` - does it make any difference? and this is called [antialiasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing)

Comment: @pskink nothing different. Maybe your thinking is that Center is the reason? I don’t think so. In my project, I use it in Column without Center, but I encountered this problem. In the example code, I can change the Center with a fixed Sizebox.

Comment: imho the only way is a `CustomPaint` but actually why would you want such workarounds to get those hard edges without antialiasing?

Comment: @pskink The designer was complaining to me that the edges looked blurry, I just picked one of the cases to test. In my project, this problem happened on Divider and edge of Card widget.

Comment: what is the value of `MediaQueryData.devicePixelRatio` on the device you are running yur app?

Comment: The devicePixelRatio is 2.625

Comment: no wonder you dont have hard edges: if you want to draw a rectangle starting at point (2, 3) flutter transforms it to physical pixels (2 * 2.625, 3 * 2.625) which are not a round numbers - but if you had a device with devicePixelRatio == 2 for example, you would see hard edges

Comment: @pskink sorry for reply late. I change height to `height: 3 / MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio,`, so that physical pixels should be exactly 3px. But still not working.

Comment: run this https://pastebin.com/5fMjZMTH with `test(7)`, `test(8)` and `test(9)` - what do you see in output_7.0.png, output_8.0.png and output_9.0.png files? does red rect in output_8.0.png have hard edges?

Answer (score 0):

you can use container's clipBehavior property to achieve this as described in this official documentation.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Clip.html

you can use following properties.

- hardEdge, which is a little faster, but with lower fidelity.
- antiAliasWithSaveLayer, which is much slower, but can avoid the
  bleeding edges if there's no other way.
- Paint.isAntiAlias, which is the anti-aliasing switch for general draw operations.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      width: 100,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,  //<-- this property 
          height: 3,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:
[image]

working: https://ibb.co/PZR1XkF

Comment: I've tried clipBehavior befor and it doesn't work... I also took a look at the screenshot you posted and it also has the edge gradient. You need to enlarge the image to the maximum, you will find that the solid line has 7px, with a gradient of 2px above and below, for a total height of 11px.

Comment: i added a video, may be you are zooming to much

Comment: It's weird.., It does look very clear in your video, but I have tried your solution myself, including hardEdge and antiAlias and antiAliasWithSaveLayer. All the results are the same as in your screenshot (but not same as video). Zooming in to the pixel level we can clearly see the blurred edge.

Comment: that do not suppose to happen